# Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from '_1218.Login' to '_1218.Models.Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is error I get :

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '_1218.Login' to '_1218.Models.Login

My code :

```
namespace _1218.Controllers {

    public class LoginController : Controller {

        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Login(Login log) {

            if (log.Username != null) {
                LoginGatewayDb LGdb = new LoginGatewayDb();
                if(LGdb.CheckLogin(log)) {
                    Session["Username"] = log.Username;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "SMS");
                }
                else {
                    ViewBag.Msg = "Username or Password is Incorrect";
                }

            }
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your portion of code, the last `}` is missing. please povide a better title to explain what you want and som tags to identify the language and technology used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You have 2 Login clases?

one in project location and one in Models folder?

Probably Your action uses 1st one, and one of your methods used 2nd one.

Comment: Yes Thats Correct Thanks a lot

Comment: @AnanthGifton please mark this answer as such if it was helpful using the checkbox next to it.